# Create Article with specified category in test environment

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex

It is neccessary to cover with unit tests such code fragment:

```
    FAQ__kav article = 
            [SELECT Title, KnowledgeArticleId, (Select DataCategoryName, ParentId From DataCategorySelections) 
             From FAQ__kav 
             WHERE PublishStatus='Online' AND Language = 'en_US' AND UrlName = :url
             LIMIT 1];
```

And I don't want to use @IsTest(SeeAllData=true) annotation, that's why I don't have access to categories and groups created manually through category assingment..
I can create, insert into database and publish article with the use of PublishingService. But I've not found the way to create and save ArticleCategory and ArticleCategoryGroup programmatically.

So, while running this code fragment in unit test environment I get exception

```
17:04:12.425 (3425626000)|FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

Can someone specify, how should I test such things?

Answer (score 0):

Go check [Salesforce Labs Public Knowledge Base v3](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000059QxXEAU) (install it in one of your konwledge-enabled sandboxes) for some ideas.

It's a free unmanaged package - meaning that you can view & modify the code as you wish. You don't have to make it work in any way - you just want to peek at the "almost-official" code.

From what I remember it's bit of a pain to unit test the Knowledge. For starters - you can't publish articles I think, you'll be only able to create them as Drafts. So that kills this bit of your `WHERE` right away.

Maybe you could make-do by changing your logic. Try SOSL instead of SOQL (the search dialect that creates results similar to sidebar search / global search in the UI). You'd be able to use the data category assignments more properly there ([`WITH` clause](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_with_data_category.htm) - to be fair it's available in plain old SOQL too). But more importantly - in unit test you can cheat by [mocking the expected output of a SOSL search](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_SOSL.htm).

Or maybe you can ditch this whole piece of Apex? Are you sure you can't achieve what you need with [`<knowledge:*>` Visualforce tags](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_knowledge_articleList.htm)?

Comment: Surely, one can publish article, quite a recent change in API like PublishingService solves this problem. I'm using <knowledge:* tags already, but I need some custom functionality to work with categories and it is difficult to unit test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Category using the following:

```
Faq__DataCategorySelection dataCategory = new Faq__DataCategorySelection();
dataCategory.ParentId = article.ID;
dataCategory.DataCategoryGroupName = 'Support_Options';
dataCategory.DataCategoryName = category;
insert dataCategory;
```

This will add your category and you can query it